# Как сделать пропорциональное изменение в spinedit'ах в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать пропорциональное изменение в spinedit'ах в Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Обрабатывать изменение значения, и присваивать его другим spinedit..